# Docker for desktop gives "Access Denied" Error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have installed "Docker for Desktop" in Windows Server 2022

I have switched docker daemon to Windows containers.

Then I am running below command:

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022 cmd.exe
```

Above command opens a interactive command prompt, where I run below command to create a file.

```
echo "Hello World!" > Hello.txt
```

But the above command gives error as "Access Denied" in the command prompt.

```
echo %USERNAME%
```

Above command gives the username as "ContainerUser". So how to give the Container user an admin rights to create a file/directory? Is there any settings to be done in the docker side?

I tried to look for what is ContainerUser, upon which I understood it is the user from the nano server image which I am running, but unable to find any proper solution for the same.
Using Windows Server 2022 VM -> Nested Virtualization and Hyper V enabled

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with this image but by default the image doesn't have root access(which is good), you can either mount wherever you want to write to if it's on your local machine or you can do chmod 777 on the folder of the host machine or you can create a new image with nanoserver as the base image and have user root or a real user with semi root access

Comment: I am a noob here, it is a image for windows container and docker server is also windows, how can i mount the folder wherever i want to write?

Comment: I did assume that when you did your echo command that you wouldn't want that to be ephemeral, so to keep whatever you make you could make a volume and so if you did -v \Window\path:\container\path and you did the echo command in the container to make that txt file it would show up in your window machine(I'm semi unsure if this would work with your access denied but at least in the past I've been able to create without root, and that way you can see if you can make a file). For long term i'd need to know the bigger use case because this is probably to test things out